# sp_BlitzQueryStore reports "multiple plans", but I can only find one execution plan. Why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, plan-cache, query-store

`sp_BlitzQueryStore` reports a particular query on several of my rows. In each of these, it reports

> Unparameterized Query, Parallel, Multiple Plans, Row estimate mismatch

However, each of these rows show the same `plan_id`, `query_id`, and `query_id_all_plans_ids`. Furthermore, I can only find one row matching that query's hash in the `query_store_plan` view. Why, then, does `sp_BlitzQueryStore` report that the query has "multiple plans"?

When I look in to the code for `sp_BlitzQueryStore`, my immediate suspicion is that joining on to `query_store_runtime_stats` is the culprit. Basically, if a query has run in N time intervals then `sp_BlitzQueryStore` will think that it has at least N plans. However, I strongly suspect that I cannot be correct because that would mean that `sp_BlitzQueryStore` is almost always wrong when giving the "multiple plans" warning.

Comment: I'm rather sad that we don't have a tag for sp_BlitzQueryStore. Query Store deserves to be popular.

Comment: See https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2423/tagging-for-third-party-tools-scripts for a discussion of tags for such things.